# Why Enumerator uses IEnumerator but never implement any method of this interface in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, enumerator

As far as I know if you uses an interface you should implement all definitions inside the interface, in this case, browsing into Enumerator struct, I noticed this struct uses IEnumerator Interface:

```
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
  public T Current { get;}
  public void Dispose();
  public bool MoveNext();
}
```

And IEnumerator is defined as this:

```
public interface IEnumerator
{
  object Current { get; }
  bool MoveNext();
  void Reset();
}
```

But, I don't see any implementation of IEnumerator  in Enumerator, how is that possible?

Even more, I try to define my own struct and I try to use IEnumerator as the same as Enumerator struct do:

```
public struct myOwnStruct : IEnumerator
{
  public  Current { get;}
  void Reset();
  public bool MoveNext();
}
```

And, the complier say there are no implementation for IEnumerator.

So, what is the explanation that Enumerator struct  uses an interface but it never provides a implementation?

Comment: They are there, implemented as private methods.  The tool you use only displays the public ones.  Look up "explicit interface implementation" in your favor C# language book.

Comment: IEnumerator is supposed to be implemented by your collection class. So whatever implements `IEnumerable` will need to implement `IEnumerator`. The Enumerator is supposed to be how you enumerate through your collection, so you have to implement it based on how your collection works!

Comment: If you're going to post code and ask about compiler errors, make sure the code in fact produces the error message in question and not a host of other errors. The last struct there has no body for Dispose or MoveNext, and T is undefined.

Comment: Oh great!!, that explain that, and which tool can I use to see the private methods implementation?

Comment: Have you looked at [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140) ?

Comment: No, I have never looked , thanks for the help!!, I'll see that link.

Comment: @HansPassant I feel like this sort of defeats the purpose of interfaces, at least from a typeclass standpoint; if you can't access the methods guaranteed by a contract, they might as well not be there, no?

Comment: Well, wrong standpoint.  The entire point of interfaces is to hide the implementation of them completely.  And you certainly can access those private implementation methods, through the interface reference.

Comment: @ap They are accessible, but only by first casting to the specific interface that defines the methods.  It's useful for providing different implementations depending on which interface is being used.  This is necessary in the `IEnumerable<T>` case because there are 2 `GetEnumerator` methods that differ only in return type, so you *must* implement at least one explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

`explicit interface implementation` is exactly used in such cases when you have to implement two interfaces having the same method signature (`Current`) and different return types (there're other uses, like hiding also).

That's, simply put, the only way to do it (compiler doesn't let you define two methods that are technically 'the same').

[Signatures and overloading](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/basic-concepts.md#signatures-and-overloading)

> The signature of a method specifically does not include the return type

Answer (score 0):

```
`Enumerator` provides explicit implementation of `IEnumerator<T>`. Implicit implementation is in the format InterfaceName.Method. So Enumerator have void  `object Ienumerator.Current { get{/*implementation*/} }` and etc.
```

If you want to implement `IEnumerator` in you own struct then you have two options:

```
public struct myOwnStruct : IEnumerator
{
  public  Current { get{/* implementation*/}}
  public void Reset(){}
  public bool MoveNext(){return true;}
}
```

or

```
 public struct myOwnStruct : IEnumerator
    {
      IEnumerator.Current { get{/* implementation*/}}
      void IEnumerator.Reset(){}
      bool IEnumerator.MoveNext(){return true;}
    }
```

More information about explicit and implicit interface implementation you can find here: [implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mhop/2006/12/13/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations/)